# Why are these headers not working? Steam login

Tags: python, request, http-headers, steam

I want to understand why the headers from the browser do not work. The authorization method has changed in Steam. Previously, everything worked on headers from the browser, but now.. The first thing to do when you login is to get an RSA key. I'm making a request using the new API. The "GET" request.

```
URL = "https://api.steampowered.com/IAuthenticationService/GetPasswordRSAPublicKey/v1/?account_name=account_name"
```

Headers from browser. If you set browser headers in the request, the response comes code 302 and redirects to the main page.

```
browser_headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7', 'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0', 'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="105", "Not:A-Brand";v="8"', 'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site', 'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1', 'Host': 'steamcommunity.com', 'Referer': 'https://steamcommunity.com', 'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty', 'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors', 'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Linux"'}
```

But if you make a request with the default headers of the requests library, then the response turns out to be correct.

```
headers_python = {'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.28.1', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
```

What's wrong with Steam servers when you use browser headers? Why does it return a redirect?

What was I trying to do:

1. I changed the accept value in browser_headers like this 'Accept': '*/*'.
2. Deleted "Referer" in browser_headers.